# Having a container fill the remaining space while having left floated and right floated blocks inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My head banner is made as such

[image]

The logo width and height are **known**. The banner takes the logo's height. The rest would be in percentage of whatever's remaining. The message fills the remaining space and floats left. The search bar and profile space floats right. All elements are centered vertically.

Here's my terrible attempt. Every solution I've tried so far have had unintended consequences.

HTML

```css
.top-banner {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:115px;
}

.top-banner .logo {
    float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:255px;
  height:115px;
  background-color:red;
}
.user-status {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.search-bar {
  width:30%;
  float:right;
}
.user-profile {
  float:right;
  background:blue;
   width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 -moz-border-radius: 37.5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 37.5px;
 border-radius: 37.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="top-banner">
    <div class="logo">

    </div>
    <div class="user-status">
        <span>You have 29 days left to your trial</span>
    </div>
    <div class="search-bar input-group">
        <input name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <button type="submit">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>  
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="user-profile">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xu17j585/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` with `media queries` set to `min-width: 768` or something.

```css
.top-banner {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 115px;
}
.top-banner .logo {
  width: 255px;
  height: 115px;
  background-color: red;
}
.user-status {
  flex: 1;
}
.search-bar {
  width: 30%;
}
.user-profile {
  background: blue;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 37.5px;
}
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .top-banner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="top-banner">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="user-status"><span>You have 29 days left to your trial</span>
  </div>
  <div class="search-bar input-group">
    <input name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <button type="submit">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="user-profile">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This really seems to have done the trick. I had experimented in other ways with the flex box to no avail. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with flexbox. If i understand you correctly you want to logo and user status always to be left and search input and user profile to left.

```
<div class="top-banner">
    <div>    
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="user-status"><span>You have 29 days left to your trial</span></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="search-bar input-group">
                <input name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <button type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>  
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="user-profile"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.top-banner {
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:115px;
}

.top-banner .logo {
    float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  width:255px;
  height:115px;
  background-color:red;
}
.user-status {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.search-bar {
  width:30%;
  float:right;
}
.user-profile {
  float:right;
  background:blue;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    -moz-border-radius: 37.5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 37.5px;
    border-radius: 37.5px;
}
```